# Flask Web App - Not sure what causes the 404 error

Tags: python, html, http, machine-learning, flask

I am developing a flask web app running on a machine learning model. The ideal result is that I can input an uvindex and it will predict a number of hourly guests to me. The web app looks like this:

[image]

But I hit the Predict button, this error keeps showing:

[image]

Below are the scripts for my app.py and html file.

app.py:

```
 import numpy as np
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
    import pickle
    import os



    app = Flask(__name__)
    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('index.html')

    def predict(to_predict_list):

        int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
        final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
        prediction = model.predict(final_features)

        return prediction

    @app.route('/final',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def final():

        data = request.get_json()

        print(data['uvindex'])
        uvindex=data['uvindex']

        # # #put everything into int
        uvindex=int(uvindex)

        to_predict_list = [uvindex]

        result = predict(to_predict_list)   
        result=int(result)

        return jsonify({ 
            'result': result
        })


    if __name__== '__main__':
        port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Weather</title>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2 style="font-size:25px ">Weather Man</h2>
        </div>


        <form id="modelForm" class="form-inline">

          <div>
            <div class="form-groupn"></div>
            <label>Uv Index?</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="1-300" id="uvindex" name="uvindex" min="1"
              max="300" required><br>
          </div>



        <div id="result" class="result">

          <button id="submitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Predict</button>

          <h4 style="color:black">Your predicted hourly guest is:</h4>
          <div id='reg' style="display:inline;">    </div>
        </div>


      </form>



    <!-- /* javascript */ -->

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

          $('#submitButton').on('click', function () {
            var uvindex= $('#uvindex').val();

            var req = fetch(
              '/app',
              {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },

                body: JSON.stringify({ uvindex: uvindex }),
              })

              // after response get data from json 
              .then((res) => res.json())

              .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                // $('#display-0').html(data.result);

                jQuery('#reg').html('');
                document.getElementById('reg').innerHTML += '$';
                document.getElementById('reg').textContent += data.result;    

                 });
                 });
                 });


    </script>  

    </body>
    </html>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Please let me know where the problem is.

Comment: What handler do you expect to work making post-request to `/app` url? May be you should add `@app.route('/app')` there?

Comment: it tries to connect to `/app` but you don't have `@app.route('/app')`. Maybe you should use different url in `var req = fetch('/app', ...)` - ie `'/final'` ?

Comment: @furas you are right. thank you